# Joins between different Databases in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to make a join between different CouchDB Databases? I know, that I can put all data into the same database, but I want to use Ubuntus DesktopCouch, which has some default databases like contacts an notes I want to use. And I don't want to "spam" those Databases with my stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to have documents from different databases in the results of a view. Your program can simply query each independent database for the docs you need.

**Update** - However, if you're wanting to create a working copy of that data for yourself in your own database, you can use replication to pull data into your database. Then you can mess with the data as much as you need, and push the updated data back via replication as well.

Comment: Interesting Idea, thank you. Is it possible to select, what should be replicated? For example only one specific type?

Comment: You can filter which documents should (not) be replicated, see http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication